# How to bind DevExpress Grid to Dictionary

Tags: grid, devexpress

I have a dictionary key value pair

```
Dictionary<string, string> Details
Details.Add("Name","ABC");
Details.Add("Number","1234");
```

How can I add this to be a datasource for devexpress grid(header less) so that the grid displays

Col1    Col2

---

Name    ABC

Number  1234

address Some Road

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    { "Name", "Abc" },
    { "Number", "1234" },
    // ...
};
var gridView = gridControl1.MainView as GridView;
gridView.PopulateColumns();
gridView.Columns["Key"].Caption = "Col1";
gridView.Columns["Value"].Caption = "Col2";
```